# How do I implement hash functions for arbitrary record types in ReScript?

Tags: reason, bucklescript, rescript

I'm exploring ReScript for the first time. I want to build a hashmap using a record type as my key type, and I'm looking for guidance on implementing the hash function.

Here's my ReScript code:

```
type pointer = { id: string, table: string, spaceId: option<string> }

module PointerHash = Belt.Id.MakeHashable({
  type t = pointer
  let hash = a => 0 /* How do I implement this? */
  let eq = (a, b) => 
    a.id == b.id &&
    a.table == b.table &&
    switch (a.spaceId, b.spaceId) {
      | (Some(aid), Some(bid)) => aid == bid
      | _ => false
    }
})
```

I looked through the docs and searched online but didn't find any guidance about how to implement the `hash` function.

In other programming languages like eg Java that expect you to implement `hashCode()`, there are ubiquitous tools to support composing existing hash functions.

```java
class Pointer {
  public final id: String
  public final table: String
  public final @Nullable spaceId: String
  /* omitting constructor, etc */
  @Override
  public int hashCode() {
    // Standard helper for implementing hashCode()
    return Objects.hash(this.id, this.table, this.spaceId);
  }
}
```

I looked at the [implementation of Belt.HashMapString](https://github.com/rescript-lang/rescript-compiler/blob/master/jscomp/others/belt_HashMapString.ml) to see if there were any hints, and it looks like HashMapString uses `caml_hash_mix_string`:

```ml
external caml_hash_mix_string : seed -> string -> seed  = "caml_hash_mix_string"
external final_mix : seed -> seed = "caml_hash_final_mix"
let hash (s : key) =   
  final_mix  (caml_hash_mix_string 0 s )
```

What is the most idiomatic way to access and compose "hash mix" functions? Are these available with a nice interface from ReScript?

Answer (score 3):

There's a built-in polymorphic hash function in the `Hashtbl` module:

```
let hash: 'a => int
```

This comes from the OCaml standard library which ReScript inherits. You can find the documentation there: https://docs.ocaml.pro/html/LIBRARY.stdlib@ocaml-base-compiler.4.10.0/Stdlib/Hashtbl/index.html#val-hash

Comment: Is there an equivalent in Belt?

Comment: @AllainLalonde no, but since `Hashtbl.hash` is available out of the box in ReScript, you don't need an equivalent in Belt.